# How to include npm packages in ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: asp.net, node.js, asp.net-mvc, npm

I'm a total novice to npm, or really any package managers.

I'm working on a ASP MVC project within Visual Studio, and I have npm and bower installed globally on my computer.
I'm trying to use the bootstrap-material-design package in my project.
I manually created a `package.json` file using Visual Studio.

I opened a CLI at the project root and ran `npm install -S bootstrap-material-design`. That created a folder `node_modules` at project root, with `bootstrap-material-design` inside. I've included these folders in my project. It also changed my package.json file. Now, it looks like this:

`{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-material-design": "^0.5.10"
  }
}`

It appears to me that the package is "included" in my project. But my question is: how do I *use* it? All the npm guides I've been reading seem to suggest I can just start using the package in my javascript code and Visual Studio will somehow know that I'm trying to use to the package. But bootstrap-material-design has CSS files and JS files it needs included on every page. Where do those folders get included? In `_Layout.cshtml`? I'm pretty stuck.

Thank you!

Comment: "But bootstrap-material-design has CSS files and JS files it needs included on every page". They don't necessarily have to be on _every_ page, although the case of this package it might make sense. So...you just include them where you need them. If you want them available in every view, then include them in the Layout view. If you want them included just in certain views, include them in those views (or use nested Layouts). The package manager doesn't do this for you because the choice is entirely dependent on how you want to use the files within your specific application

Comment: Yes, please add scripts and style tags (as like how you include css and javascripts in HTML) in the _layout.cshtml. You have got the npm thing done right. What you need from here is to get the scripts included in your ASP MVC project.